# While query from two SQL statements?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, while-loop

I have two SQL queries: the first query pulls all `criteria` from the database and the second query looks for any `criteria completed`:

**SQL Query 1**

```
//get all criteria for section
$getcrit = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, category_id, section_name, criteria  
FROM prepare_criteria
WHERE category_id=? AND section_name=? ");
$getcrit->bind_param('is', $cat_id, $sectname);
$getcrit->bind_result($criteria_id, $category_id, $section_name, $criteria);
$getcrit->execute();
$getcrit->store_result();
$row_cnt = $getcrit->num_rows();
$getcrit->fetch();
```

**SQL Query 2**

```
//get any checked criteria from db
$getcompcrit = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT prepare_criteria_complete.criteria_id, prepare_criteria.id, prepare_criteria.criteria, prepare_criteria_complete.business_id, prepare_criteria_complete.category_id 
FROM prepare_criteria_complete, prepare_criteria
WHERE business_id=?
AND prepare_criteria.id=prepare_criteria_complete.criteria_id");
$getcompcrit->bind_param('i', $business_id);
$getcompcrit->bind_result($cc_criteria_id, $criteria_completed_id, $comp_criteria, $business_id_db, $category_db);
$getcompcrit->execute();
$getcompcrit->store_result();
$gc_row_cnt = $getcompcrit->num_rows();
```

I'm then writing a `while` loop to check for any `criteria completed`:

```
if ($gc_row_cnt >=1)
{
    while ($getcompcrit->fetch() )
    {
        if ($cc_criteria_id==$criteria_completed_id)
        {
            echo $criteria_completed_id." ";    
        }
        if ($criteria_id!=$criteria_completed_id) 
        {
        echo $criteria_id." ";  
        }
    }
}
```

The second `if` doesn't function as expected.
I know there must be a cleaner way of doing this!
Maybe a `JOIN` statement?

Comment: @nbk I'm trying to look for any `criteria_id` in the 'completed` table and match them to the `criteria` in the `prepare_criteria` table.

Comment: Because I'm using the query to echo out checkboxes and check them if the `completed_cririteria_id` is true.

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can use next single query:

```
SELECT 
    pc.id, pc.criteria,
    coalesce(pcc.business_id, 'not complete') business_id,
    coalesce(pcc.category_id, 'not complete') category_id
FROM prepare_criteria pc
LEFT JOIN prepare_criteria_complete pcc 
    ON pc.id=pcc.criteria_id AND pcc.business_id=?;
```

The query use [coalesce](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_coalesce.asp) operator for return 'not complete' string in case `prepare_criteria` record have not matched record in `prepare_criteria_complete` table.

Comment: Can you explain what `coalesce` means please?

Comment: I just added some explanation. Try to run query and look if result is suitable for your case.

Comment: Looks interesting. I want to pass the `id` to checkboxes and check the box if the `criteria_completed` is true, for example:
//if criteria_completed_id{ 
//do something... 
}
 else{
 //do this..
}
How can I do this?

Comment: what does the `pcc` mean in the `LEFT JOIN` query?

Comment: `pcc` is short alias for long table name `prepare_criteria_complete`, `pc` is alias for `prepare_criteria`

Comment: It partly works, but just trying to understand your statement. I need to filter the results by `business_id`: I've added `WHERE business_id='4'` but this fails?
Also - do you need need to list BOTH tables in the `FROM` statement?

Comment: Because you not provided tables schema, i try to guess the right query. Look it now after join condition was fixed.

Comment: It does work and show criteria that are/are not complete. The short alias's are awesome! How can I pass the results to variables I can query?
I previously used:
`$qry->bind_result($qry_id, $qry_criteria_id, $comp_criteria, $business_id_db, $category_db);`

Comment: @jmiller what prevents you from doing the same?

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev It's close...I need the `category_id` to retain it's value so I can query it?

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev with a couple of tweaks, I've got this working! I removed the `AND pcc.business_id=?` clause and added `WHERE pc.category_id=?` to filter the results.
I then used an `if` statement to match `business_id`. 
Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

**THE SQL QUERY**

```
$qry = $mysqli->prepare("
SELECT 
    pc.id, pc.criteria, pc.category_id,
    coalesce(pcc.business_id, 'N') business_id
FROM prepare_criteria pc
LEFT JOIN prepare_criteria_complete pcc 
    ON pc.id=pcc.criteria_id 
    WHERE pc.category_id=? ");
$qry->bind_param('i', $cat_id);
$qry->bind_result($qry_id, $qry_criteria, $qry_cat_id, $qry_bus_id );
$qry->execute();
$qry->store_result();
$qry_row_cnt = $qry->num_rows();
```

PHP

```
if ($qry_row_cnt >=1)
                            {
                                while ($qry->fetch() )
                                {               
                                    if( ($qry_bus_id==$business_id) )
                                    {
                                    //criteria is checked
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                    //criteria not checked
                                    }   
                                }
                            }
```

Comment: Adapted from @slavarozhnev's solution above.

Comment: this code doesn't seem to be doing what is should do. I fixed the formatting for you though

Comment: It works fine. I've rolled it back to my version - as I use the `while` loop in the main body to echo html checkboxes (the sql is in my functions).